# Не работает условие if-else в скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, условия

Всем привет! Есть магазин и виджет с корзиной. По идее при добавлении товара в корзину должен появляться контейнер с классом fixed-bottom, но проблема в том, что условие if-else (когда корзина пуста в списке "cart_list product_list_widget" отображается li с классом empty) не отрабатывает и контейнер отображается всегда, хоть у него и прописано в стилях display:none

```js
    if ($(".cart_list.product_list_widget li").hasClass("empty")) {
      $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
    } else {
      $(".fixed-bottom").show().fadeTo("slow");
    };
```

```css
.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
      <li class="empty">Корзина пуста.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Не вижу в вашем примере разметки элемента li с классом empty.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, читайте внимательно вверху
(когда корзина пуста в списке "cart_list product_list_widget" отображается li с классом empty)

Comment: Так отобразите его в вашем примере-то. Почему у вас пример разметки не соответствует вопросу?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, хорошо - добавил вверху. фишка в том, что изначально он моей разметке отсутствует и подгружается в виджет автоматом

Answer (score 1):

В какой момент выполняется приведенная вами проверка - после подгрузки корзины или до? Во втором случае причина несрабатывания проверки очевидна.

Comment: по идее конечно проверка должна до выполняться, чтобы знать загружать блок или корзина пустая. В чем очивидность ошибки?

Comment: До того, как корзина загрузилась - в ней нет элемента `li` с классом `empty`. Вы же сами это сказали.

Comment: да, это сработало - теперь все ок, за исключением момента, когда товары добавили, потом обновили страницу или перешли на другую, страница обновляется и в ней остается товар, но корзина находится в скрытом режиме и не отображается, т.к. срабатывает на событие кнопки заказа и по умолчанию о на не отображается - как это можно обойти проверкой?

Comment: Очевидно, подобную проверку следует делать каждый раз, когда ее результат может измениться. Т.е. при каждом обновлении корзины.

Comment: какого плана проверку - вот в чем вопрос?

Comment: Ту самую, которую вы делаете.

Comment: так вы же сами говорите, что проверка срабатывает до загрузки страницы и empty не видит

Comment: И где противоречие?

Comment: в том, что при загрузке не отрабатывает это условие if ($(".cart_list.product_list_widget li").hasClass("empty")) и соотв не хайдится $(".fixed-bottom").hide(); а сразу отображается- а мне это не нужно

Comment: Ну так сделайте, чтобы отрабатывало

Comment: логично, что если я прошу помощи, то не знаю как это сделать..

Comment: Что вам мешает сделать эту проверку после обновления корзины?

Comment: это как подскажите?

Comment: Находите то место, где загружается корзина и пишите там то, что вам надо. Если вы не можете найти где она загружается - то так и надо говорить, а не насиловать мозг. Если же вы не можете отделить проблему "у меня не работает условие" от "я не могу найти куда надо поставить работающее условие" - то вы идиот.